# Incorrect output values with gluUnProject... why?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a simple Square with openGL es 1 and Android 1.5. The square is painted on the center of the screen.

I want that when the user press on the screen, or moves the finger on the screen, the square get's moved to that position. For do this i tryed with GLuUnProject, i tryed to obtain the opengl coordinate that matches with the window XY coordinate touched with the finger (to translate the polygon to that coordinate in the future), and i'm writting the coordinates on the LogCat.

The coordinate's i'm receiving are not true cordinates, are wrong coordinates. For example this logcat represents a horizontal movement to the right of the screen:

```
11-07 15:54:37.221: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: -0.003236022
11-07 15:54:37.221: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.047979668
11-07 15:54:37.241: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: -0.003236022
11-07 15:54:37.251: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.047807075
11-07 15:54:39.110: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: 0.03469036
11-07 15:54:39.110: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: 0.04418271
11-07 15:54:43.021: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: -0.029469538
11-07 15:54:43.021: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.034172554
11-07 15:54:43.051: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: -0.026708115
11-07 15:54:43.051: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.034172554
11-07 15:54:43.081: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: -0.018596433
11-07 15:54:43.081: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.034172554
11-07 15:54:43.111: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: -0.013073588
11-07 15:54:43.111: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.034172554
11-07 15:54:43.141: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: -0.0039263717
11-07 15:54:43.141: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.033999965
11-07 15:54:43.162: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: -0.0011649576
11-07 15:54:43.162: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.033827372
11-07 15:54:43.191: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): X: 7.335304E-4
11-07 15:54:43.191: DEBUG/XXXXXXXXX(213): Y: -0.033654787
```

This is the source code:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {  
private float INITIAL_Z = -35.0f;   
private Context context;
private Square square;
private float xrot;                 //X Rotation
private float yrot;                 //Y Rotation
private float zrot;                 //Z Rotation    
private float z = INITIAL_Z;            //Profundidad en el eje Z
private float x = 0.0f;             //eje X
private float y = 0.0f;             //eje Y

private MatrixGrabber mg = new MatrixGrabber(); //create the matrix grabber object in your initialization code    
byte horizontal=-1; //0: LEFT  1:CENTER  2:RIGHT
byte vertical=-1; //0: TOP  1:CENTER  2:BOTTOM
float startX=-1;
float startY=-1;
float xMovement=0.0f;
float yMovement=0.0f;
private boolean movement_mode=false;

public MySurfaceView(Context context, Bitmap image, int width, byte horizontal, byte vertical) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); //fondo transparente
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); //fondo transparente
    //Transformamos esta clase en renderizadora
    this.setRenderer(this);
    //Request focus, para que los botones reaccionen
    this.requestFocus();
    this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    square = new Square(image);
    this.horizontal=horizontal;
    this.vertical=vertical;
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    MyGl=gl;
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);               //dithering OFF
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Texture Mapping ON
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Smooth Shading 
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Depth Testing ON
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0); //fondo transparente
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);         
    //Cargamos la textura del cubo.
    square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);     
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //Limpiamos pantalla y Depth Buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    //Dibujado
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);           //Move z units into the screen
    //gl.glScalef(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);            //Escalamos para que quepa en la pantalla
    //Rotamos sobre los ejes.
    gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //X
    gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //Y
    gl.glRotatef(zrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   //Z
    //Dibujamos el cuadrado
    square.draw(gl);    
    mg.getCurrentProjection(gl);
    mg.getCurrentModelView(gl);

}

//si el surface cambia, resetea la vista, imagino que esto pasa cuando cambias de modo portrait/landscape o sacas el teclado físico en móviles tipo Droid.
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       
        height = 1;                         
    }
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset Projection Matrix
    //Aspect Ratio de la ventana
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset Modelview Matrix
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float [] outputCoords=getOpenGLCoords(event.getX(), event.getY(), 0);
    x=(outputCoords[0]/outputCoords[3]);
    y=(outputCoords[1]/outputCoords[3]);
    //z=outputCoords[2]/outputCoords[3];
    Log.d("XXXXXXXXX", "X: "+x);
    Log.d("XXXXXXXXX", "Y: "+y);        
    return true; //El evento ha sido manejado
}

public float[] getOpenGLCoords(float xWin,float yWin,float zWin)
{
    int screenW=SectionManager.instance.getDisplayWidth();
    int screenH=SectionManager.instance.getDisplayHeight();
    //CODE FOR TRANSLATING FROM SCREEN COORDINATES TO OPENGL COORDINATES
    float [] modelMatrix = new float[16];
    float [] projMatrix = new float[16];
    modelMatrix=mg.mModelView;
    projMatrix=mg.mProjection;          
    int [] mView = new int[4];
    mView[0] = 0;
    mView[1] = 0;
    mView[2] = screenW; //width
    mView[3] = screenH; //height
    float [] outputCoords = new float[4];
    GLU.gluUnProject(xWin, ((float)screenH)-yWin, zWin, modelMatrix, 0, projMatrix, 0, mView, 0, outputCoords, 0);
    return outputCoords;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `z` (the one you pass to `glTranslatef`)? And what values does `outputCoords[2]/outputCoords[3]` take (if you uncomment the line in `onTouchEvent`)? With the initial z and no rotation it should be something like -35.1.

Comment: The z value is -4.800247, i need to use z on this class because the distance of the object must be the distance represented with that value of Z. Also i have to say that outputCoords[2]/outputCoords[3] = 4.7002473 alwawys. Im passing 0 as winZ value to GluUnProject becase i dont know which value haves winZ :S

Comment: Do you have a rotation in it (e.g. a non-zero value for `yrot`), because with no rotation the result should rather be `-4.9` instead of `4.7`. Ah, forget what I said, `4.7` is alright.

Comment: i'm not applying any rotation for obtain these values

Comment: I think the problem is that i am giving 0 value to winZ on GluUnProject, because i dont know how to obtain the winZ value :S. i only can get X and Y from the touch on the screen

Comment: A value of 0 corresponds to the near plane of the viewing volume. And with this the values you get are quite correct, I think. Of course they might not correspond to the 3d object you want to touch, but they are correct, given the screen depth of 0 you pass into `gluUnProject`. So I think everything works fine. Getting the correct depth of the object you clicked is another problem (to which you already asked a question), which seems to be a bit more difficult in ES.

Comment: I think you need to create a Ray and determine the intersections with the far and near plane. Look here:

http://android-raypick.blogspot.nl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values seem quite reasonable. You get an x value that becomes larger and larger (negative values with decreasing absolute value) and a y value that stays roughly the same, which corresponds to a movement to the right (assuming you don't have any non-zero rotation in your transformation pipeline).

And a resulting z coordinate of `4.7` is also reasonable, given a z-translation of `-4.8` and a near value of `0.1`. And with such a z-translation and a field of view of 45 degrees, your resulting x and y values should indeed be quite small (roughly around [-1,1], I think).

So I think your code works just like it should. What coordinates would you have expected? Please don't say something on the order of pixels.

Comment: then my problem is the Z value as you said in the comments of the question, i know that something is going bad because if i translate the polygon to the given coordinates the polygon is not being translated correctly. I really have a problem with the winZ value... i really need to know how to obtain it, did you know how to do it?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 That's already treated in another question of yours. If I come to know an answer I'll post it. But on ES it seems to be not that easy, especially ES 1 where you can't use fragment shaders.

Comment: @AndroidUser99 If you translate it using the resulting (x,y,z) value (instead of the already existing translation, not additionally, of course) the polygon should be at the given location. But it will of course be inside the near plane and may just be clipped away because of precision issues. If it's not clipped away, it should cover the whole screen, which is also not what you want. Like said, determining the correct depth is another question and the answer to this question here ("why does `glUnProject` not work correctly?") is, "it does work correctly indeed, just not like you expect it to".

Comment: i think i have a very huge problem with this, i dont know how to solve it:(